# jQuery DataTables add rows dynamically removes some initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have successfully worked with jQuery DataTables and they look and function great.  But I'm switching to adding rows dynamically and some of the formatting disappears when the rows are added.

1.The background colors of the columns disappear
2. the selected clumn background color disappears as well 
3. and if you click on the column headers it kills all the rows and resets the DataTable to its initial state with all the background colors and select column background back as they should be.

This is how the table is initialized"

```
oTable = $('.utable').dataTable( {"sDom": 'rt',"sScrollY":"260px", "bPaginate":false, "bFilter":false, "bInfo": false});
```

Here is how I add the new rows:

```
document.getElementById('tbdy').innerHTML="<tr id='zrow16' class='gradeX'><td id='d1'>None</td><td id='d5' class='ralign'>None</td><td id='d6' class='ralign'>None</td></tr>";...<tr id='zrow17' class='gradeX'><td.... "
```

Comment: we need more code, the one you posted is certainly not enough to figure out a solution.

Comment: You should be calling fnAddData.  http://www.datatables.net/api

Comment: Thank you I believe that you are right!  But I need a checkbox also in the Row and I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To add row you should use [fnAddData()](http://datatables.net/api), you shouldn't append a `<tr>` otherwise you break the table

```
var giCount = 2;
function fnClickAddRow() {
  oTable.fnAddData( [
    giCount+".1",
    giCount+".2",
    giCount+".3",
    giCount+".4",
   '<input type="checkbox">']
  );

  giCount++;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to insert a checkbox and I'm not sure how to do that with fnAddData()

Comment: @DennisKean you can insert also some html in your row

Comment: @DennisKean i updated my answer, also look here http://live.datatables.net/oputug/edit#javascript,html (justclick thetable to add a row)

Comment: Could you show me a simple example on how to do that? Never mind...  you anticipated me...  you rock...

Comment: @DennisKean i updated my answer and provided a link that does justthat! :)